# Cannot use Swift on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: swift, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

After conscientiously following the install instructions on Linux from swift.org, I encounter an issue where it is not possible to compile anything on a Ubuntu 18.04 machine. The REPL seems to work but during compilation (when calling `swift build`) the following error appears:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
```

There are more details in the full bug report [[SR-9093]](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-9093). I don't know at all what to do to solve this issue, there are similar problems already mentioned in other bug reports, for instance on this really old one [SR-35].

What should I do?

Comment: Note that your bug report has unanswered comments from Apple engineers.

Comment: Is question still open ?

Comment: @DinkoPehar Yes it is! :)

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming that you had already installed the **libstdc++** successfully and you have set the permissions properly. But I really doubt that it was installed correctly but it was installed with corruption of some sort. The corruption occurred because you didn't install libstdc++ via a package manager. Result was some form of weirdness in the package manager database which effected the overall functioning system. Exactly why adding something to a folder should change anything at all. I don't know why this happens, unless the folder is hot i.e symbolically linked to a program which doesn't have any tolerance for hacks like simply copying a file into the folder. So for now try to install the **libstdc++** again. Below is the link to the file to again download the correct program and this is compatible with amd64.
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-5/libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10_amd64.deb

 
And below are some link to help

1. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1425470
2. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=808045
3. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=808045
4. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libstdc%2B%2B
5. https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libstdc++6

Comment: Unfortunately this apparently didn't work either. The bounty ended and I wanted to thank you as you made the most complete answer. I hope it will help others who would stumble upon this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Install libstdc++

`sudo apt install libstdc++6`

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately this has already been done and didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems *possible* that the apt install did not run the `ldconfig` program, which should be run to add the library to the list of those which `ld.so` knows about.

It looks like you can do it manually:

`sudo ldconfig`

> **IMPORTANT** **CAVEAT**: I don't have Ubuntu and haven't been able to test this. And it's a `sudo` command. Run at your own risk, YMMV, etc.

If this does not work, it's possible that a file called `/etc/ld.so.conf` is not set up to search the directory where libstdc++ ended up. I wouldn't dare try to describe how to fix that.

Answer (score -2):

`sudo apt install -f`

The command above should install any missing dependencies.

Comment: Hello, I tried this too and it didn't change anything